# JQuery Quovolver malfunctioning.... Cookies?

Tags: jquery, quovolver

I'm using Quovolver to display revolving quotes on a couple of web pages.

It works fine unless a user goes to another tab in his browser and then returns. If he does this all manner of funny business can start to happen. Maybe multiple quotes displaying at once, quotes displaying only partially, quotes flashing quickly and not revolving... All far from acceptable.

A lot of Googling etc later I'm at a bit of a loss to explain what's going on and am bereft of ideas on how to fix it... But I do need to fix it!

A friend suggested it may be something to do with cookies and that I should disable them but I need them for tracking facebook and google ads etc.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: You're sure it's not just the plugin that sucks, I haven't read the code, but I did notice it does some rather funny business with `eval` a few places -> **https://github.com/sebnitu/Quovolver/blob/master/jquery.quovolver.js**

Comment: It could just suck. It's definitely not behaving as it should. If I don't get a good answer on here I'll probably just have to look at other ways of doing it.